# Is peer-to-peer possible between two distant devices?

Tags: windows-phone

Are there limitations that would prevent from establishing a tcp/ip socket connection between two distant devices? (Not on the same WiFi LAN.)

[Edit]

I missed this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx

I'll try it as it seems like the usual client/server snippet, but for WP, so that looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly device to device due to dynamically assigned IP address visibility etc.  You might have to expose a web service on the public internet for this purpose.  Basically a web service both devices can see and communicate with.  (ex. Heroku, Amazon AWS).  One device can keep a blocking connection ("Comet") while the other device initiates connections.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "visibility"? You mean the public IP pointing to Internet?

Comment: Assume device A and B.  These can't directly talk using TCP.  However you deploy a lightweight web service on amazonaws.com.  That's a publicly available site and both A and B can see it.  So to have A send a message to B it gets mediated via amazonaws.

Comment: Hum. Maybe I'm forgetting something from my networking knowledge, but do you talk about a total impossibility to communicate directly via public IP:Port, or about the fact that these infos need to be shared before establishing a direct connection?

Comment: Uh, just realized I can't avoid the port forwarding. Nobody is constantly in DMZ.

Comment: Generally speaking in the real world 2 arbitrary devices in different environments can't make tcp/ip connections to each other.  This is due to NAT, firewalls etc.  There aren't enough IPv4 addresses for this.  This isn't really a bad thing; imagine if my toaster could arbitrarily decide to make tcp connection to your microwave oven.